# Как отправить сообщение в лс в дискорде при заходе на сервер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Итак, у меня есть такой код:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(random.choice([
        f'Привет, {member.name}, добро пожаловать!',
        f'Дарова {member.name}, обсутраивайся на сервере)',
        f'{member.name}! Добро пожаловать)']
                                               )
    )
```

Он отправляет сообщение о заходе на сервер. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы он отправлял в личные сообщения тоже самое. Т. е. что-то по типу `member.отправить('Спс за джоин на сервер!')`.

Comment: Странно, подобное очень быстро можно загуглить. Я думаю, это дубликат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. Просто возьмите вашего участника и введите `member.send('Ку! Спс за джоин на сервер!')`.

Answer (score 3):

Как говорит документация, это можно сделать через `client.fetch_user()`. Он возвращает объект discord.User, а потом этому пользователю можно отправлять сообщения. Как пример:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.fetch_user(user_id=member.id).send('Спс за джоин на сервер!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот код с подробным объяснением.

### Код

```
@client.event ## Создаем инвент)
async def on_member_join(member): ## Далее в через member в скобоччках берем нашего пользователя
  await member.send(random.choice([ f'Привет, {member.name}, добро пожаловать!', f'Дарова {member.name}, обсутраивайся на сервере)', f'{member.name}! Добро пожаловать)'])) 
## И последняя строчка. Бот выбирает рандомное сообщение нашему пользователю.
```

### Итоги

И так, теперь мы сделали так, что при заходе мы берем пользователя, а дальше уже отправляем ему в личные сообщения случайное сообщение. Надеюсь, я вам помог! Удачного вечера)

[image: Скиншот]

Comment: Ты на полном серьезе просто ответил тоже самое, что и я?

Comment: @Ma3rX ага - вообще без отличий [почти]

Comment: так тут совсем легко, даже думать не надо, о чем речь?

Comment: @ForevorBase о том, что у нас с тобой ответы одинаковые. И галочку мне поставили задолго, как ты тут это выкатил. Какой смысл все это повторять?

Comment: когда я писал ещё не было галочки, как я помню

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но @Ma3rX и правда написал тоже самое и галочка до вашего "ответа" уже была.